# Tv card application

Tags: c#, television, windows

I have a gadmei pt228f tv card plugged in to my pc.i need to write a c# application in order to display tv in my application.can someone give me a idea to start with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the MediaPortal project. It got support for lots of different TV cards (and it's written in C#)

http://wiki.team-mediaportal.com/1_MEDIAPORTAL_1/18_Contribute/4_Development/Subversion_%28SVN%29

Answer (score -2):

Read card driver/API documentation.  Design/implement an interface from your app.  Start calling stuff.

Rgds,
Martin